# pg_rewind: source and target cluster are on the same timeline

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I tried to synchronize between `source/target` clusters by using `pg_rewind` by the following command.
**And I know 100% the content of in the `source/target` clusters are not the same anymore.**

```
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_rewind --source-server="192.168.100.100 user=postgres password=mypassword"  -D /var/lib/pgsql/12/data --progress
```

but `pg_rewind` gives the following message

```
pg_rewind: source and target cluster are on the same timeline
pg_rewind: no rewind required
```

I didn't understand how the content of `pg_wal` & `base` directories are different between `source/target` but `pg_rewind` did't realize that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_rewind` only undoes data modifications on the target server later than the latest common checkpoint.

Modifications that have happened on the source server after the latest common checkpoint are ignored – these will be recovered anyway when the target server becomes a standby of the source server.

So the target server probably was shut down cleanly before the source server got promoted.

The message about the timeline is coincidental, it is not the cause of the second message.